# Python and C Integration with CLion

Tags: python, c, clion

I work on a project that uses python script to run C code on CLion (with Python community addition).
I want to test the integration between Python and C. How can I get into the C code during a debug session while running the python code?

Comment: If switching between different programming languages in the same debugging session doesn't work (and I wouldn't expect it to!), then the way I worked around this was to specify `python` as executable to debug, with arguments loading a script which in turn loads the Python module written in C++ that I wanted to debug. I didn't do that in CLion but VS2005 though, but it should work nonetheless.

Comment: Work is in progress
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5797